# Rails/Cucumber - Hosting error testing omniauth (provider: facebook) - (URI::InvalidComponentError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, devise, cucumber, omniauth

I am facing an error trying to configure omniauth for integration testing purpose with cucumber (I set up Omniauth through Devise as the wiki provides)

Please see below:

```
Scenario: Test                       # features/omniauth.feature:3
  Given I am signed in with facebook # features/step_definitions/omniauth_steps.rb:1
    bad component(expected host component): http://www.example.com (URI::InvalidComponentError)
    /Users/benoit/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/uri/generic.rb:395:in `check_host'
    /Users/benoit/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/uri/generic.rb:409:in `host='
    ./features/step_definitions/omniauth_steps.rb:2:in `/^I am signed in with facebook$/'
    features/omniauth.feature:4:in `Given I am signed in with facebook'
  Then I open the page               # features/step_definitions/debug_steps.rb:5
```

Here are my files:

### omniauth.feature

```
Feature: OmniAuth

  Scenario: Test
    Given I am signed in with facebook
    Then I open the page
```

### omniauth_steps.rb

```
Given /^I am signed in with facebook$/ do
  visit "/auth/facebook"
end
```

### support/env.rb

```
OmniAuth.config.test_mode = true
OmniAuth.config.mock_auth[:facebook] = {
  'uid' => '12345',
  "user_info" => {
    "email" => "foobar@example.com",
    "first_name" => "foo",
    "last_name" => "Bar"
  }
}
```

### initializer/devise.rb

```
case 
  when Rails.env.production?
    config.omniauth :facebook, 'XXXX', 'XXXX', 
    {:scope => 'email, offline_access', :client_options => {:ssl => {:ca_file => '/usr/lib/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt'}}}
  when Rails.env.development?
    config.omniauth :facebook, 'XXXX', 'XXXX'
  when Rails.env.test?
    config.omniauth :facebook, 'XXXX', 'XXXX'
        OmniAuth.config.full_host = 'http://example.com' # issue 257  
end
```

(Reference: [issue 257](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/issues/257))

### routes

```
devise_scope :user do 
  get '/auth/:provider' => 'users/omniauth_callbacks#passthru'
end

devise_for :users, :path => "", :controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks => "users/omniauth_callbacks" }
```

As info, I also configured my facebook test_app with the following URL: http://example.com/

I would be pleased to know if someone has a thought/experienced this.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to add :

```
Before do
  Capybara.default_host = 'example.com'
end
```

to your support/env.rb file,  try also commenting out :

```
OmniAuth.config.full_host = 'http://example.com' # issue 257
```

from your initializer/devise.rb file.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I'm assuming too little here but just in case.. have you set up an authentications controller and associated routing?

```
# /config/routes.rb
match "/auth/:provider/callback" => "authentications#create"
```

**Edit:** Sorry I just realised you said you set everything up as the wiki provides. I guess you've done this so. I guess I'll leave it here anyway.

To learn about how to set up the Authentication Controller you should watch Ryan Bates [screencasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=omniauth) on the subject. They are really an excellent resource.

I have a controller written with full facebook authentication that I can post if you like? Just leave a comment.

Comment: Hi Duckyfuzz, thanks for your answer! You're right I should add my route. (also I change the host as you can see here https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/issues/257, given me another error anyway). I saw the ryanb screencast but didn't follow it as I thought the code is more consice in the devise wiki since Devise supports omniauth integration now. (https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth:-Overview). So now I have a URI::InvalidComponentError :(

Comment: I'm not sure to be honest. I've never set up omniauth using the devise module so it's very hard for me to tell what it's supposed to look like. Sorry I can't help more.